# Pass function call as a function argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Code:

```
def function1(a,b):
    return a-1,b-1
def function2(c,d):
    return c+1,d+1

print function1(function2(1,2))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Python\scripts\twitter_get_data.py", line 6, in <module>
    print function1(function2(1,2))    
TypeError: function1() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Why the above error?

Comment: function1(*function2(1,2))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions are returning tuples, because `return` only gives back one item.  You can "unpack" the tuple returned by prepending it with an asterisk.  The syntax will look like this:

```
print function1(*function2(1,2))
```

Comment: Thanks! Please similar question I face http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988139/appending-the-return-values-to-a-set-of-list-directly