# Appending the return values to a set of list directly

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two list list1 and list2 and I have to append the result to both of them with the values returned by func().

```
item1,item2=func()
list1.append(item1)
list2.append(item2)
```

Is it possible to replace the above by a single statement? In other words, how can I append the returned tuple to two lists without creating any temporary variables?

Edit:
Please compare the efficiency and reason in the loss as to why. I am unable to understand it.

Comment: For two different lists and two different items, I do not think there are any ways to replace them with a single line

Comment: `for i, l in zip(func(), [list1, list2]): l.append(i)`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My guess is that it feels weird to save references and then only use them once.

Comment: What you have is quite readable, and the fact that you're using temporary variables isn't a negative: with a suitable choice of names, they can make the code even *clearer*. All else being equal, if you have the choice between a simple, straightforward solution and a clever, flashy solution, pick the simple one every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to do this, but:

```
map(lambda l,v: l.append(v), (list1, list2), func())
```

In Python3 you need to force the `map` to iterate:

```
list(map(lambda l,v: l.append(v), (list1, list2), func()))
```

Comment: :D functional programming gone bad. This looks hackish, but it's definitely cool.

Comment: Functional programming applied very precisely for the submitted problem. Upvote.

Comment: If `append` wasn't a mutator then I'd consider it legitimate to write this and do something with its return value (if a bit fiddly, what with two of the arguments of `map` being longish). But in Python we don't like to hide side-effects, so I also agree that it has somewhat "gone bad". In real life I don't use `map` in ways that ignore its return value.

Answer (score 2):

A tricky way:

```
(lambda x,y: list1.append(x) or list2.append(y))(*func())
```

Equivalent to

```
def lambda_func(x,y):
    return list1.append(x) or list2.append(y)

lambda_func(*func())
```

You can also use zip if lists in same size:

```
list1[:], list2[:] = zip(*zip(list1,list2)+[func()])
```

I don't think it's efficient than your code posted.
Thanks to Padraic, it would be failed if lists in different size.

Comment: This will fail unless the lists are always  the same size

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, brainstormed and `lambda` works

Comment: @LittleQ Can you please elucidate more on how you came up with this. It would be greatly helpful.